# PHP not writing in MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have an HTML page with input fields where I'm using PHP to validate and eventually write into my MySQL Database called 'fantasymock'.  If validation is successful, the user is directed to an empty page called thankyou.php (using for testing purposes), which I am being directed to. But unfortunately, the data is not being written into the database.

I've looked on the web and previous SO posts and don't see a similar situation likes mines.  Can someone look at it and possibly find the issue? Code is somewhat long and apologize. Thank you.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$emailErr = $userErr = $passwordErr = $cpasswordErr = $firstErr = $lastErr = $teamErr = "";
$userid = $email = $username = $password = $cpassword = $firstname = $lastname = $teamname = "";

// The preg_match() function searches a string for pattern, returning true if the pattern exists, and false otherwise.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //Validates email
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email = NULL;
        $emailErr = "You Forgot to Enter Your Email!";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
            $email = NULL;
            $emailErr = "You Entered An Invalid Email Format"; 
        }
    }
    //Validates Username
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $username = NULL;
        $userErr = "You Forgot to Enter Your Username!";
    } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
        }
    //Validates password & confirm passwords.
    if (empty($_POST["cpassword"])) {
        $password = NULL;
        $cpassword = NULL;
        $passwordErr = "You Forgot To Enter Your Password!";
        }
    if(!empty($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"] == $_POST["cpassword"])) {
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
        $cpassword = test_input($_POST["cpassword"]);
        if (strlen($_POST["password"]) < '7') {
            $password = NULL;
            $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!";
        }
        elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
            $password = NULL;
            $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
        }
        elseif(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$password)) {
            $password = NULL;
            $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
        }
        elseif(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#",$password)) {
            $password = NULL;
            $passwordErr = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
        }
    }
    elseif(!empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $password = NULL;
        $cpassword = NULL;
        $passwordErr = "Please Check You've Entered Or Confirmed Your Password Correctly!";
    }
    //Validates firstname
    if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
        $firstname = NULL;
        $firstErr = "You Forgot to Enter Your First Name!";
    } else {
        $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        //Checks if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
            $firstname = NULL;
            $firstErr = "You Can Only Use Letters And Whitespaces!"; 
        }
    }
   if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
        $lastname = NULL;
        $lastErr = "You Forgot to Enter Your Last Name!";
    } else {
        $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
        //Checks if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
            $lastname = NULL;
            $lastErr = "You Can Only Use Letters And Whitespaces!"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["teamname"])) {
        $teamname = NULL;
        $teamErr = "You Forgot to Enter Your Team Name!";
    } else {
        $teamname = test_input($_POST["teamname"]);
    }
    if ($email && $username && $password && $cpassword && $firstname && $lastname && $teamname) {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        @mysql_select_db("fantasymock") or die("Unable To Connect To the Database");

        //Variable used for the primary key in User Table in Database.
        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $teamname = $_POST['teamname'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$userid', '$email', '$password', '$cpassword', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$teamname')";
        mysql_query($query);

        mysql_close();
        header("Location: thankyou.php");
        die();
    } else {
        echo '<p align="center"><strong>Errors on page</strong><br><br></p>';
    }
}
/*Each $_POST variable with be checked by the function*/
function test_input($data) {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<!--The htmlspecial() function prevents from hackers inserting specific characters in fields with malicious intent-->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center" bordercolor="white" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2"><strong>Registration</strong></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><br></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">E-mail:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Username:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;username" value="<?php echo $username;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $userErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Password:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;password" value="<?php echo $password;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Confirm Password:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="password" name="cpassword" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;confirm password" value="<?php echo $cpassword;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $cpasswordErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">First Name:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;first name" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $firstErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Last Name:</td>
                    <td align="left"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;last name" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $lastErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Team Name:</td>
                    <td align="left" width="30%"><input class="largeTextBox" type="text" name="teamname" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="&nbsp;team name" value="<?php echo $teamname;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><span class="error"><?php echo $teamErr;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><hr/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input class="bigButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the "@" before `@mysql_select_db`, and enable the error reporting to see any errors.
Add following at the begining of the php file:
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Your INSERT-query contains a HUGE syntax error. It should look like: `INSERT INTO table (columnName1, columnName2) VALUES (value1, value2)`. Yours is missing the whole column-field. This is allowed, but ONLY if you fill all columns EXACTLY (which often enough does not happen). You could've found out yourself if you add error-reporting to your code. After executing the query, check if it returned `false`. If so, an error occured, which can be retrieved using the `mysql_error()` function.

Comment: Where are you getting the $userid variable from? There is no such form field, yet you seem to have used $_POST['userid']...

Comment: @iCode4U No, I actually do not get any errors. I get directed to the thankyou.php and all. The validation works good too. Its just not writing in dB.

Comment: @Kamehameha I'm using userid as my primary key, which will be auto incremented in the dB.

Comment: @tularis I read your comment and missed the error you mention so I did not know what you were talking about. Went back a second time and caught it. Thank you

Comment: Another very important part is that you really should not use the `mysql` extension anymore. It has been officially deprecated. Rather, you should use either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO). Both support `prepared statements` which increase the safety of your queries and make sure that you will not be the victim of SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if your query was succesfull or not. if not show the error.

```
if (!mysql_query($query)) 
{
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

And in your database, are all the columns strings(varchar) or are there also integers because if so you wont succeed .

like this

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
```

i assume userid is a integer but you just assign it from post to var this var will be a string.

in order to get a integer you should something like this

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$userid+=0;
```

And if your primary key is set to auto-increment you should not insert anything to that column. It will be done automaticlally

Comment: thats the first thing I checked. All my columns are varchar except the primary key ('userid')

Comment: read the last part because you are trying to do that. i think.

Comment: this was helpful. I actually do not get an Error. Notice: Undefined index: userid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Manny\Portfolio\register.php on line 97
Invalid query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: The weird part is I used the exact same foundation for a previous project where I left the userid undefined but that project did write into my dB.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't solve the problem you're having but hopefully it helps.

try the query as

```
 "INSERT INTO user (`email`,`password`,`cpassword`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`teamname`)VALUES 
   ('$email', '$password', '$cpassword', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$teamname')"
```

let the db driver handle assigning the id using auto increment.

You should also be aware you have some nasty sql injection vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you aren't handling MySQL errors. After you call a query, you should always have some kind of error checking. For [mysql](https://www.php.net/mysql_error) you should use mysql_error. For example:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$userid', '$email', '$password', '$cpassword', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$teamname')";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
```

That should tell you your error.